# OSX Spotlight plugin to search local Git repo history?

Tags: macos, git, search, spotlight

Is there a spotlight plugin for OS X that would enable one to find, using spotlight, items in the history of a Git repository?

Let's say that I have a series of text files in my git repo, and in the comments for one of my files has been deleted at some point in the editing process. I could search the git repo through the command line but I would like to search via spotlight. Is there a tool I could use for this?

Comment: Sounds very useful for developers with local git repos. Did you ever find a solution for this ? If not then I'm wondering if it's something that could be easily implemented via [Flashlight](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com) ?